# wp8: Remove all from ScheduledActionService

Tags: windows-phone-8, alarm, scheduledactionservice

How do I remove all alarms from a [ScheduledActionService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

`ScheduledActionService.remove()` method requires a name also does `find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<ScheduledNotification> notifications = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<ScheduledNotification>().ToList();
foreach (ScheduledNotification notification in notifications)
{
    ScheduledActionService.Remove(notification.Name);
}
```

Comment: I replaced Reminder with ScheduledNotification so it will work with Reminder and Alarm. Thanks!